# how to get Selected Value from Dropdownlist in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i filled my dropdownlist by angular js from json. But selection is not working. How can i select dropdownlist item?

TaskTypeDefinitionController.js:

```
 var roleList = [{"id" :1, "value" :"test" },{"id" : 2, "value" : "test2"}];
        roleList.then(function (data) {
            $scope.roleList = data;
            var jsonArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                jsonArr.push({
                    id: data[i].roleName.serno,
                    value: data[i].roleName.value
                });
            }
            $scope.Names = jsonArr;
            console.log(jsonArr);
        });
```

html(View) :

```
<select class="form-control" placeholder="Görev Tipi Adı" ng-
options="field.id as field.value for field in Names" ng-model="Name"  
required></select>
```

Comment: you got selected value in your `ng-model` added `console.log($scope.Name);` and check in browser's console.

Comment: But selection is not working means default value is does not set?

Comment: Selected value will be present in the ngModel i.e. Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selection is not working means you need to set the default value of dropdown. If yes then try this below code instead of your code.

```
 var roleList = [{"id" :1, "value" :"test" },{"id" : 2, "value" : "test2"}];
        roleList.then(function (data) {
            $scope.roleList = data;
            var jsonArr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                jsonArr.push({
                    id: data[i].roleName.serno,
                    value: data[i].roleName.value
                });
            }
             jsonArr.push({id:0,value:"Select Name"});
             $scope.Name=jsonArr[jsonArr.length-1];
            $scope.Names = jsonArr;
            console.log(jsonArr);
        });
```

### Explain

The `Name` is your model name of dropdown. It is `undefined` on your first time. So I think it's may be showing blank. So you need to assign a value to the `Name` object. In my code have assign a value(Select Name) to the `Name` Object.

in this code

```
         jsonArr.push({id:0,value:"Select Name"});
         $scope.Name=jsonArr[jsonArr.length-1];
```

Comment: connect with me for job offer : yusuf.karatoprak@rdlab.com.tr. i am serious!

Comment: Seriously? ha ha !! 04rameshrajendran04@gmail.com. Send mail to this address !