# How to set default value to select when I am using ng-model and and ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am asking this question because ng-model overwrites default value in select tag. So I need to set `<option value="-translation.published_at" selected>{{ 'Newest first' | translate }}</option>` to be a default value. This is my code:

```
    <div class="filter__order filter--select p-rel">
        <select id="order" class="text-dark-gray" ng-model="sortedBy" ng-change="filterByDate(sortedBy)">
            <option value="-translation.published_at" selected>{{ 'Newest first' | translate }}</option>
            <option value="translation.published_at">{{ 'Oldest first' | translate }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can I know, what is your question here?

Comment: How to set default value to select when I am using ng-model and and ng-change? That is my question.

Comment: How can we set this if you are using Hard-coded values.

Comment: I need to make a example. So I used values that are hard-coded. ng-model here is a value attribute. So, tell me, how can I explain you are problem if I don't give you code?

Comment: Are you using ng-option or not?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008435/how-to-get-selected-value-from-dropdownlist-in-angularjs?rq=1

Comment: I don't need ng-option for two elements. I am asking is there a way to do this with hard-coded values?

Comment: That's what you did already with `selected` attribute.

Comment: No I didn't. When i reload page, i can see a blanc select with no default value. When I reload page, I want to se a  <option value="-translation.published_at" selected>{{ 'Newest first' | translate }}</option> as selected value

Comment: This is the main issue for you, You should add this in your question as well. Then only we can understand the exact problem.

Comment: But i did that. Read a question: How to set default value to select when I am using ng-model and and ng-change? And then I explained: 
I am asking this question because ng-model overwrites default value in select tag. So I need to set <option value="-translation.published_at" selected>{{ 'Newest first' | translate }}</option> to be a default value. Did you even read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Assign value to the ng-model of select

    <select required="required" class="form-control control-sm"  ng-change="settingtestValue(ItemValue)" ng-model="ItemValue" name="info_bcsWorkItem">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option ng-repeat="bcsItem in bcsWorkItemList" value="{{ bcsItem }}" >{{ bcsItem }}</option>
</select>

$scope.ItemValue= "your value you want to assign";
```

Comment: I don't need <option value="">--Select--</option>. I need to make: ``` <option value="-translation.published_at" selected>{{ 'Newest first' | translate }}</option>``` become a default value

Comment: Then directly define ng-model of select with your default value inside controller, that sould work

Answer (score 1):

Apply ng-init

```
<select id="order" class="text-dark-gray" ng-model="sortedBy" ng-init="sortedBy= yourDefaultValue" ng-change="filterByDate(sortedBy)">
```

**OR in controller side after change event**

```
$scope.sortedBy= yourDefaultValue;
```

Comment: This is half-correct answer but I need to display text in select input.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use ng-init or inside angular controller:

```
$scope.sortedBy = "your default value";
```